# Why is SQL Server 2012 Recommending This Index Be Created?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
Select SubId, Max(ReadTimeLocal)
From dbo.PanelWorkflow 
Where ProcessNumber IN (802,1190,1605,1620,1645,1660,1695,1790,1990,2690,2795,2990,3090,3290,3590,3790,4190,4390,4590,5000,5200,5400)
Group By SubId
```

I have the following index on the dbo.PanelWorkflow table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PanelWorkflow_ProcessNumber_Lineage] ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow]
(
    [ProcessNumber] ASC,
    [Lineage] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [SubId],[ReadTimeLocal]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

The query plan from SSMS looks as follows:

[image]

SSMS is recommending  I create the following index (with an impact of 54.3)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow] ([ProcessNumber])
INCLUDE ([SubId],[ReadTimeLocal])
```

Does anyone know why it's recommending I create an index that essentially exists already, and is not using the one that does exist?

There are 830 million rows in the table. Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: SQL Server like to believe he is the most intelligent guy on the face of earth, and trust me most of the times he is right :) I would create a smaller table create this index on it and see what it does.

Comment: Yeah, but a human created the index that currently exists, and SQL Server is choosing not to use it. Presumably if I create the index it is suggesting, which is essentially what I have now, it will use it. I don't get it?

Comment: SQL Server suggestion are based on the its own some Tuning Advisor Algorithms it uses to come up with the best execution plans and when SQL Server feel like existence of another some Index B can help it to come up with a better execution plan it gives you a suggestion to create it. and most of the time it is a right suggestion, but again you have to make the decision that whether you will be executing this query quite often or not , is it really viable to create this index or not. If its a query I run once in a month I wont bother but if its something I do often, I will probably go for it.

Comment: Just for kicks: have you tried actually creating the index and see if SQL Server would really use it in your execution plan? Database Tuning Advisor is known to have weaknesses in that sometimes it suggest already existing indices, or an index (like in your case) which is really already present in slightly modified form.

Comment: As for why it is not using the one that does exist. From the line thickness coming out of the operators it looks as though neither the `IN` filter or the `GROUP BY` reduce the number of rows involved much at all. Your current plan can use the clustered index, ordered by `SubId`, to avoid a sort. Doing multiple seeks on `ProcessNumber` doesn't look like it materially reduces the number of rows involved and then means the results of the seeks would need to be combined in a memory consuming sort or hash aggregate.

Comment: I don't know if the table is partitioned. Our DBAs have been partitioning some tables, but I don't know if this is one of them. ProcessNumber is an int and Lineage is a char(6).

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify, SSMS is not recommending that index, it is from the query engine/optimizer. Just to note as well a good MSDN article notes some [limitations to the Missing Index Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345485%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The fact that your current non-clustered index contains `[ProcessNumber]` and `[Lineage]` the query engine found simply scanning the clustered index of the table to be more optimal. It is suggesting an index strictly on `ProcessNumber` because the query is filtering on that column only. I believe if this is also the column that the clustered index is based on then your non-clustered indexe will be ignored by the query optimizer.

I would look into all the missing indexes the optimizer sees for this table and evaluate the current unused indexes as well.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like SQL Server is simply recommending a skinnier index that covers the query better than the existing one would (and currently the clustered index is selected anyway). I'm not sure what the data type of `Lineage` is but it seems to think it would be wasteful to read the data from that index. Even with the skinnier index being suggested, I don't know that your query could still be satisfied by a seek, so it's unlikely to provide a huge improvement over what you have now. If this is a common query (meaning these are the same `ProcessNUmber` values you always query for), you may consider a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SubID ON dbo.PanelWorkflow(SubID, ReadTimeLocal DESC)
  WHERE ProcessNumber IN (802,1190,...);
```

Comment: Definitely assuming it is the skinnier index that still covers the query - and not bad idea to look into filtered index either if those are the values you typically search for.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the only way this barely makes sense is if `Lineage` is so wide as to not be useful. (Per comments, this is not the case)

Consider forcing the query to use the existing index and see if the performance is better.

```
SELECT SubId, Max(ReadTimeLocal)
FROM dbo.PanelWorkflow WITH (INDEX(IX_PanelWorkflow_ProcessNumber_Lineage))
Where ProcessNumber IN    (802,1190,1605,1620,1645,1660,1695,1790,1990,2690,2795,2990,3090,3290,3590,3790,4190,4390,4590,5000,5200,5400)
GROUPBY BY SubId
```

On the other hand, the index you may want to try is:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow] ([ProcessNumber], SubID, ReadTimeLocal DESC)
```

This may be a better solution because it will have ReadTimeLocal already sorted. Having it in an include does not have it sorted

Or if you wanted to be really picky

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[PanelWorkflow] ([ProcessNumber], SubID, ReadTimeLocal DESC)
WHERE ProcessNumber IN (802,1190,1605,1620,1645,1660,1695,1790,1990,2690,2795,2990,3090,3290,3590,3790,4190,4390,4590,5000,5200,5400)
```

This will restrict your index to only the processNumbers desired.

Comment: Lineage is only a char(6) and isn't referenced in this query. I am trying the Index hint.